# Algorithm or and python implementation of getting a minimal list of prefix suffix of a list

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to find an algorithme that with a list of word, give the minimum list of prefix and suffix such that every word is the concatanation of a prefix and a suffix.

ex :

```
[banano, ananas, applenas, appleno, neo, neas]

=> [bana,anan,e, apple] [as no]
```

Is that possible ?

Comment: Wait. So you say you have a list of words and given prefixes and suffiixes can you figure out all the different combinations of those that result in words from your list?

Comment: That sounds NP-hard... if not undecidable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is not uniquely defined.  For example, for language [aa, ab, bb] the solution might be either [a, b] [a, b], or [aa, ab, bb] and empty string.

The problem can be understood as an instance of the minimum string cover problem (just assume that each string starts with a mandatory begin-string character, and ends with another mandatory end-string character.  The allowed covering dictionary would then consist of all prefixes and all suffixes of all words in the input language.

The general string cover problem is NP-hard, but as soon as you impose the rule (here implied by the appearance of begin-string and end-string characters) that only a fixed maximal number of strings (here, two) may cover any given input string, it becomes [polynomially solvable](http://siam.omnibooksonline.com/2012ALENEX/data/papers/019.pdf).

Here is a C++ implementation of a [solver](http://code.google.com/p/string-cover/) of minimum string cover problems.